# SQL query, finding out the minimum of the data set

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT MIN(DateDiff("yyyy",[Employment History].[Date of 1st Promotion],Employee.[Date of Birth])) AS MinimumPromotionAge 
FROM [Employee],[Employment History] 
WHERE(([Employee].[Promotion]="Yes") 
AND ((Employee.EmployeeID)=[Employment History].[EmployeeID]));
```

I have created this query in order to find the youngest average age of promotion, but there are issues with the punctuation used. Wondering if there was any advise that could help with this problem.

Comment: i doubt you are using MySQL because brackets are SQL server syntax.

Comment: which database you are really using ????

Comment: Using Access 2016, coding to help create a query

Answer (score 0):

You can ease the reading a bit with alias:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(DateDiff("yyyy", E.[Date of 1st Promotion], E.[Date of Birth])) AS MinimumPromotionAge 
FROM 
    [Employee] As E,
    [Employment History] As EH
WHERE 
    E.Promotion = "Yes" 
    AND 
    E.EmployeeID = EH.EmployeeID;
```

but syntax seems correct, so you must be more specific about the error.

Also, *DateDiff* will not return the age, only the difference in calendar years.

To calculate the age, use a function like this:

```
Public Function Years( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of year counts.
' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased step wise one year from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2000-11-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' 2000-12-16. Leap year correction modified to be symmetrical.
'             Calculation of intDaysDiff simplified.
'             Renamed from YearsDiff() to Years().
' 2000-12-18. Introduced cbytMonthDaysMax.
' 2007-06-22. Version 2. Complete rewrite.
'             Check for month end of February performed with DateAdd()
'             after idea of Markus G. Fischer.

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDate1, datDate2)
  ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
  ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a full 12 months period
  ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", -intYears, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      ' Offset negative count of years to continuous sequence if requested.
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  ' Return count of years as count of full 12 months periods.
  Years = intYears - intDiff

End Function
```

and, in the query:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(Years(E.[Date of Birth]), E.[Date of 1st Promotion]) AS MinimumPromotionAge 
FROM
<snip>
```

Comment: How do you return the age?